# Unmounted Macintosh HD - Data partition / fsroot tree is invalid

Tags: macos, catalina, filevault, apfs

MBP late 2012, SSD encrypted AFPS macos 10.15.3

I can pass the first filevault password for Macintosh HD but then classic macos kernel panic screen because the the data partition cannot mount.

[image]

[image]